# Using a matrix as a dictionary value and performing numpy matrix operations in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, brackets

I have a dictionary with key and value (it was given to me).
When I read a key to extract the value, I get something like this:
matrix([[1.234, -4.056]])

I call this value A.

I define a variable as below

```
B = np.matrix([0, 0])
```

B is a running sum of A times a group of scalars,

```
for i in range(0, n):

     B =+ A*scalar[i]
```

The problem is that the output has the format

matrix([[xxx , yyy]])

and I need

matrix([xxx, yyy])

that is, I do not want the double brackets.

Comment: Don't use `np.matrix`. It will be removed soon.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `numpy.array` not a `numpy.matrix`. The `np.matrix` [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) is a 2D data structure, `np.array` is an `nd` dimensional structure.

If you look at `B.shape` immediately after creating you will discover that it is `(1,2)`, not `(2,)` as you intended.

```
B.A.reshape(2,)  # or B.A1
```

will give you a `np.array` that is 1-dimensional.

**NumPy arrays ARE NOT equivalent to NumPy matrices, the meaning of operations is different between the two, for instance `*` is a dot product for `matrix` but an element wise product for an `array`.**

Comment: Thank you, especially for the .shape tip.